# Question regarding uniform spaces and equicontinuity

Tags: general-topology

[image: my problem is in prop 27, cannot prove it. Can use definition before. Notice that p-closure is the closure of G in the open point topolgy]

For extra notations: C(E,F) is the set of all continuous functions from E to F (topological spaces).
Can anybody help me prove the proposition?

Comment: There is presently no question here.

Comment: I think he wants us to proof the proposition.

Comment: yeah, sorry. If you could help me prove the proposition it would be wonderful.

Comment: Recall that the closed entourages form a basis of the uniformity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be any entourage in the uniformity of $F$, and $x$ be a fixed point in $E$. Then let $W$ we any symmetric entourage such that $W \circ W \circ W \subseteq V$, which can be done by the standard axioms for a uniformity. Then find $U$ open in $E$ that contains $x$, and such that for all $f \in G$, and for all $y \in U$ we have that $(f(x), f(y)) \in W$.

I claim that $U$ now works $\overline{G}^{(pw)}$ as well for the original $V$.

So let $y \in U$ and $g \in \overline{G}^{(pw)}$. Now consider the following set:

$$O = \left\{f \in F^E \mid f(x) \in W[g(x)] \text{ and } f(y) \in W[g(y)] \right\}\text{.}$$

This is a basic neighbourhood of $g$ in $F^E$ in the product topology, and so by the assumption that $g \in \overline{G}^{(pw)}$ we have some $f \in O \cap G$. We then know that (as $y \in U, f \in G$ and by the way we chose $U$) $(f(x), f(y)) \in W$ and as $f \in O$ we know that $(f(x), g(x)) \in W, (f(y), g(y)) \in W$. So by how we chose $W$ we know that $(g(x), g(y)) \in V$, as required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, didn't you mean on the second line, W composed with W and not 2 compositions of W?

Comment: @AvivEshed No, I mean 3 compositions. This is well-defined for relations (composition is associative) and follows from the uniformity axiom for this, applied twice. If it were a metric codomain I'd use $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ when I start with $\epsilon$, because I do a triangle inequality with three terms, essentially...

Answer (score 0):

What is $p$-closure?    If a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ works for $G$, does it also work for $\overline{G}$?

Comment: that is exactly what we want to prove. that V or a subset of it will work for G closure. p-closure is the closure of G in the point-open topology.