# Question regarding uniform spaces and equicontinuity number 2

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Following the already answered question:

[Question regarding uniform spaces and equicontinuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095918/question-regarding-uniform-spaces-and-equicontinuity)

in the context of proposition 27. How do we know that indeed every element in the p-closure of G is a continuous function from E to F and not just any function? (Because equicontinuity suggests, by its definition, that the set P closure of G should be a subset of C(E,F) and not of F^E.)